# How come my exported (fbx) files are weird and transparent?

Tags: export, import

After exporting an fbx file, and reimporting it, the models all look weird and look transparent, and I think it has to do with the material.

Answer (score -1):

The blend mode for the materials, under materials tab>settings changed & become wrong after being exported. Try the different options to fix it. This is a bug of Blender version 2.92. Download the previous version without the bug here: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.91/

Comment: I appreciate this note, but where did you find that it was a bug? Is there a bug tracker entry for it?

Comment: I think there's a bug report system. I'm not that integrated with the Blender community so I'm not sure how Blender bug report cataloging works. I'm assuming it's a bug since it's wrong, shouldn't be wrong, and it isn't present in the previous version.